# Evaluate the following limit and find alpha and beta (given the limit exists):

Tags: limits

Evaluate the following limit, assume that the limit exists and has a non zero finite value : $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt[{n}^{2}]{1!2!3!\cdots n!}}{{n}^{\alpha}}=\beta$$
Also find $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

I have tried to solve this question by equating the limit to $L$ and taking log on both sides, but I am not able to understand how do I tackle with the $\sqrt[{n}^{2}]{x}$ part.

Since this is of the $\frac{{\infty}^{0}}{\infty}$ form I am unable to use the $L'Hospital$ rule, please provide an approach for solving this problem directly or converting it into 0/0 or $\infty$/$\infty$ form.

Comment: Do you know Stirling's formula?

Comment: No, i am not familiar with it.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162142/compute-the-limit-of-frac1-sqrtn-left11-cdot-22-cdot33-cdots-nn-rig